# How to divide CSV to two different Strings in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to divide CSV into Two String LHS_String and RHS_String. For Example, I have the below CSV -

```
customer^id,record^id
customer^fname,record^first_name
cusomer^gender,record^gender
```

The Output should be like -

```
LHS_String : customer^id
RHS_String : record^id
```

Comment: How look like you php code?

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Harshit can you explain exactly what you want ?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am currently doing the same by converting CSV to an Array and then using array_column() function, and fetching the columns values from an array. But I was not able to put the values into string and skip the steps of conversions

Comment: You still need to show us your attempt and tell us where it goes wrong/what result your getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, read over http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Example:

```
<?php
$data  = "customer^id,record^id\r\n";
$data .= "customer^fname,record^first_name\r\n";
$data .= "cusomer^gender,record^gender\r\n";

$p1 = explode("\r\n", $data);
$p2 = array();
foreach($p1 as $key => $line){
  $p2[$key] = explode(",", $line);
}

echo "LHS_String : " . $p2[0][0] . "\r\n";
echo "RHS_String : " . $p2[0][1] . "\r\n";
?>
```